# How to automatically close uwp applications

Tags: c#, uwp

I have two questions, first: how to let the uwp application perform a function, automatically close the uwp through the code instead of letting the user click the close button on the top right; second: how to minimize the uwp application to the taskbar at startup, not directly on the desktop, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you have to keep in mind is that using `CoreApplication.Exit` and `Application.Current.Exit` closes the app, but it does so without going through the normal app suspension - for the system it appears as a "unexpected termination". I also think the certification guidelines are against this approach.

As for taskbar minimization - this is currently not supported. If you need this functionality, you will need to build a WPF app packaged as UWP app using the Desktop Bridge.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [static exit method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication.exit.aspx):

```
public void CloseApp()
{
    CoreApplication.Exit();
}
```

or Use the non-static method ():

```
public void CloseApp()
{
    Application.Current.Exit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. How can I minimize it when starting uwp?

Comment: For minimising, Check this out:- https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/18076333-allow-an-window-to-minimize-programatically